# Make aliens believe that you are not harmful

Tags: aliens, language

Consider one day wake up and find yourself on an Alien planet.
Now, you don't wanna die and you don't understand their language.

How can you make aliens believe that you are not harmful.

Comment: Hello. Please see [this meta post](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3300/49)

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! We need more information to help you with this question, as this is very broad and whether an answer is good or not is only up to you, as we don't know what kind of story you are aiming for. It looks like this is more of a story-question than WorldBuilding. For example: What kind of aliens are we talking about? If you have a moment please [take the tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [visit the help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Please, not only keep that in mind, but also visit linked sites and edit your question, OK? And if it will be put on hold, don't despair. It only prevents people from answering so you could edit it without worrying about invalidating too many existing answers. It will be put on review each time you edit, and I believe we have quite high reopen rates here.

Comment: Don't struggle while they're dissecting you

Comment: I just saw that you already accepted an answer. That's fine of course. If that answer helped you with your question it's your decision to accept it. But your question was asked only 37 minutes before (at the point of writing this). There are only 34 views. A lot of regulars on WB haven't seen your question yet and a question with an accepted answer might(!) discourage others from answering. In general you should try to wait a day or two before accepting an answer, as there are many creative people here in a lot of different time zones. Just a tip for future questions.

Comment: + to Secespitus' comment. It's highly likely that a regular with better hindsight could provide a better answer. It's possible to change the accepted answer though, so keep that in mind in case something better comes up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided they don't see *you* as a threat, it's highly unlikely they'll kill you if they have any semblance of intelligence.

### Common misconception based on movies:

There's always the assumption that any alien life-form is harmful, but it remains as just that, an **assumption**. There's no guarantee they *won't* kill you, but nothing proves otherwise, either.

There are several factors to take in when faced with such a situation, such as your immediate surroundings, the alien's appearance, nearby (or held) objects, etc...

The aliens themselves could be expecting something from an unrecognizable life-form, so standing still is (most-likely) only going to feed their curiosity.

### The aliens themselves could be afraid of YOU.

since you've mentioned an alien "***language***", let's assume that these aliens have human-like intellect. Then it would depend on what **kind** of alien you're looking at.
If a researcher encounters a non-before seen apparition, they'll want to study it. Make that into a normal person, and they won't want anything to do with it. A hunter would want it as a trophy, a bully would want to instill fear into you, etc.. The possibilities are limitless.

### TL;DR

Basically, the answer to this question is, that there is no answer. You're just going to have to run, until the situation changes.

Comment: If aliens are afraid of you, you're going to be killed soon. Fear leads to anger, anger leads to the dark side. :D Whenever an advanced civilization (like western explorers and consquistadors) have made contact with primitive tribes, things usually end badly even if there was no ill will by any side.

Comment: @Rekesoft The thing is, that it depends strongly on how advanced the alien civilization is. Therefore, there's really no exact answer to this question. there are several psycological tendencies to take in when guauging a person's violence. Out of my own personal experience, i wouldn't kill someone (or something) even if my life is threatened. I'm sure most modern humans with no military expertise are similar.
Granted, a bad outcome is a possibility, but it's not absolute. 

We can't rule out the chance that the aliens themselves are a peaceful race either.

Comment: True, but the point is not if the aliens are peaciful individually, but the mob's psychology. Most humans are peaciful, individually speaking, but mobs often exhibits violent behaviours.

Comment: Depending on the situation. On a ratio of "an entire civilization" to 1, i'm sure even a mob of angry people with pitchforks wouldn't kill a strange object immediately without a proper reason.

Which is where the setting (alien's psycology, psyche, overall mental state)  comes into play, which would, in turn, change the current question completely. We're also forgetting that they're _aliens_, not humans. If could have an intellect equal or higher than a modern human, then without taking into account their ethics and culture, it's a bit of a stretch to label them as murderers on first sight.

Answer (score 3):

This depends more on the aliens than on you. There are tribes in the rainforest that have killed every explorer that dared to visit them. Others have been very friendly. You might not even have a chance. Think of it like this: If an alien appeared in a rural area where people still believe in demons, the creature would be dead within hours. If it landed in a modern city for example, it might remain unharmed for the rest of its life.

I always recommend people that want to go into first contact or time travel kind of fiction to learn about the exploration of tribes that have no contact with civilization. Explorers also have different techniques they use to establish contact and that no harm is intended.

Comment: -1 I don't think people in Mongolia or Simbabwe are more violent just because the GDP per capita is inferior to that of the Netherlands. If it's not racist, it's at least too western-centric. Mongolian nomad tribes are reknown for its hospitality to strangers, for example.

Comment: @Rekesoft We are not talking about a traveler here but about a monster from outer space. If you truly believe it would survive in a rural area in a developing country where there are people that believe demons are real (as was the case until shortly after the 2nd WW in England for example), this is your thing, but I believe you are dead wrong here and need to learn about other cultures. However, I have modified my comment to not make it look like I'm saying all of people X are mad and stupid. But please think before posting next time as will I

Comment: If landing in a country where people still believes in demons is a mesure of anything, then landing in the middle of US' Bible's belt would be the most dangerous place to land at. Your choice of Mongola or Simbabwe must have been an involuntary slip of mind, but it reflects a western-centric sense of superiority and that's why I downvoted it. A careful edition would have been more polite (and discrete) than a downvote and a comment, but I'm afraid I'm not allowed to do editions.

Comment: @Rekesoft You can suggest an edit. It just takes two people to approve your edit if you are under 2,000 reputation. After that you can instantly edit. But please keep in mind not to change the author's intention when editing.

Comment: So if I had mentioned the bible belt and Beijing instead of my examples, you would have kept quiet? I can do that. I'm here to please, you know. I would still recommend learning a bit about different cultures. Never did I intend anything to be derogatory. A couple of hours in an online forum and already I'm regretting my decision to help people because of the great pedants like you. Accusing someone from the west of being western centric is like complaining that a dog thinks like a dog

Comment: @Raditz_35 I highly recommend leaving out real-life analogies and "analogies". Neither revision correspond in any way with [intentional murder map](http://www.geocurrents.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/World-Murder-Rate-map.png), for example. Accusing nations and regions out of the blue is bad thing to do, no matter who you accuses, and it is totally irrelevant to the question as asked. This site is about **fictional** worlds. Please, **do not bring real life politics** here, unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: I really do not want to start a discussion about it. Please read carefully and inform yourself before making such accusations against me. My whole argument depends on examples. I have specifically mentioned two areas that have very unusual perception of certain things compared to most western people. I have edited my post, why still the downvotes?

Comment: See [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice): *Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At all.* You point at some nations and religions as especially murderous. I believe this falls under this point of site rules. If you absolutely feel you need to point your finger at specific real life people, make sure you have really, really good real life examples or statistics of them doing such things. And think twice if maybe you could rather stick to fiction.

Comment: Again, we are talking about space monsters and not a human walking there and being killed by the villagers. I have those examples, I specifically wish not to make this discussion about examples as you recommended as well earlier. Please do not expect me to follow up with any statistics regarding space monsters being killed in what country and how many per year. I only pointed out that monsters might be less tolerated some places - read my comments PLEASE. I also want to point out that the other guy should edit his post because there are good people living in the bible belt

Comment: (in a perfect world, we could've discussed why I think certain areas and cultures are worth looking into if you want to make your aliens hostile towards your character, yes, but I do not talk to internet people often and I forgot about their  nature)

Comment: @Raditz_35 I wouldn't concern yourself, we live in an age where everyone's considered a racist etc, it's just hyper-sensitivity at work, I thought your answer was fine, less advanced societies are more inclined to drastic responses to the unknown, I think that's fair. If anyone wants to claim Mongolia or Zimbabwe is equally advanced to the west, I suggest they wake up from their delusions, and come back to the real world.

Comment: I like to believe that it's miscommunication. Call me an optimist if you like

Comment: Upvoted to balance the typical politically correct downvote with the typical Christian bashing. No one should be lectured about western-centricity for making a comment that asks people to study other cultures.

Answer (score 1):

Sit and do nothing, unless prompted by an Alien. You'll probably die anyway, but that's your best bet for showing that you're not harmful.